# Distribution Plot with Gradient Fill in Python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, gradient, kernel-density

I'm trying to create a density plot with a gradient fill in python like this:

[image]

I've attempted to do so using this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 1))
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='Overall Rating', fill=True, palette='viridis')
...and
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='Overall Rating', fill=True, cmap='viridis')
```

Neither work, both outputting this plot:

[image]

I've searched all over for a method to do this in python, but no luck. I've tried implementing the methods from [this answer by @Diziet Asahi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926533/gradient-fill-underneath-each-histogram-curve-python) but can't wrap my head around it. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926533/gradient-fill-underneath-each-histogram-curve-python)

Comment: @BigBen I reviewed this code and attempted to implement it but was unable to do so for a single plot

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your attempt to do so, so someone can spot the problem.

Comment: Honestly it's so confusing I have no idea how to apply that code to my dataframe but will keep trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to grab the ax: `ax = sns.kdeplot(...)` and then execute the inner part of the `for` loop in @Diziet Asahi's solution with that `ax`.

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set_theme(style='white')
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
ax = sns.kdeplot(data=iris, x='petal_length', fill=True)

sns.despine()
cmap = 'turbo'
im = ax.imshow(np.linspace(0, 1, 256).reshape(1, -1), cmap=cmap, aspect='auto',
               extent=[*ax.get_xlim(), *ax.get_ylim()], zorder=10)
path = ax.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
patch = matplotlib.patches.PathPatch(path, transform=ax.transData)
im.set_clip_path(patch)

plt.show()
```

[image: kdeplot with gradient fill]